# How can I kill TCP port 16969 in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, tcp

I have an application which uses TCP port 16969. It sometimes requires a quick software kernel reboot on the fly. But if I launch it too fast, I am locked with

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use

So I want to trigger my Bash script which can kill any running or listening port with 16969, but how can I do that?

```
$ lsof -w -n -i tcp:16969 # this gives me a list of 50 lines but how can I kill them all?
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think that:

```
lsof -i tcp:22 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Should do the trick.

To double check what commands it wants to run before letting it loose add an `echo` before the `kill` like this:

```
lsof -i tcp:22 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}' | xargs echo kill
```

It'll then list the PIDs that it would ordinarily kill

Comment: @jordanm No it isn't. without `grep LISTEN` you will be trying to kill the column headers too, i.e., **PID**.

Comment: @dmvianna `awk '/LISTEN/ { print $2 }'`. `awk` can do everything `grep` can do. It is redundant.

Comment: Will this kill the process or only the connection?

Answer (score 24):

Have you tried using tcpkill?

example:

```
tcpkill -i eth0 port 21
```

Comment: `tcpkill` will kill the network stream but not the processes bound to the port

Comment: It seems a reasonable solution given the ambiguity in the question.

Comment: It's a superior to killing the process. I don't want to kill my webserver when there are too many requests.

Comment: this is the perfect solution when you want the processes to keep going

Comment: This solution requires root permissions.

Answer (score 18):

```
fuser -k 16969/tcp
```

can free that port. This is  a useful command that can be used to close ports, whichever it is.

Comment: **Note that this will kill the processes that are attached to the specified ports!**

Comment: fuser kills the process, there isn't the best way for kill sockets

Answer (score 5):

I often get this problem using JBoss in Netbeans...

#### My solution :

In a terminal type :

```
 sudo netstat -lnp | grep 8080
```

Then it display something like:

```
 tcp6       0      0 :::8080       :::*        LISTEN      1722/java
```

Then use:

```
 kill 1722  //replace 1722 by the PID you found.
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: This is a solution in centos.

Comment: This will kill the process :(