# How to close TCP connections in Odoo Docker

Tags: python, docker, tcp, odoo, odoo-11

I use standard odoo docker

[dockerfile](https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/master/11.0/Dockerfile)

And use [google-cloud-pubsub](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-pubsub/)

My code

```
@api.model
def sub_pub_auth(self, project):
    account_file = project.account_file
    content_base64 = base64.b64decode(account_file).decode('utf-8')
    service_account_info = json.loads(content_base64)
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
        service_account_info)
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient(credentials=credentials)
    return subscriber

@api.model
def listen_server(self):
        subscriber = self.sub_pub_auth(project)
    ...
    def callback(message):
        print('Received message: {}'.format(message))

    future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, 
callback=callback)
    a = True
    while a:
        time.sleep(2)
        a = False
        future.cancel()
```

Result
I have many open connection

> tcp        1      0 172.17.0.88:48392       216.58.209.45:443       CLOSE_WAIT  1/python3
>   tcp        1      0 172.17.0.88:32886       216.58.209.45:443       CLOSE_WAIT  1/python3
>   tcp        1      0 172.17.0.88:33256       172.217.20.173:443      CLOSE_WAIT  1/python3
>   tcp        1      0 172.17.0.88:34612       172.217.20.173:443      CLOSE_WAIT  1/python3
>   tcp        1      0 172.17.0.88:58190       172.217.20.173:443      CLOSE_WAIT  1/python3
>   tcp        1      0 172.17.0.88:59278       216.58.209.45:443       CLOSE_WAIT  1/python3
>   tcp        1      0 172.17.0.88:53138       216.58.209.45:443       CLOSE_WAIT  1/python3

How to close them?

UPD
Now have cool message

```
2018-07-24 08:44:48,378 10502 INFO ? google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber._protocol.streaming_pull_manager: Observed non-recoverable stream error 499 Locally cancelled by application!
2018-07-24 08:44:48,379 10502 INFO ? google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber._protocol.streaming_pull_manager: Observed non-recoverable stream error 499 Locally cancelled by application!
2018-07-24 08:44:48,379 10502 INFO ? google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber._protocol.streaming_pull_manager: RPC termination has signaled streaming pull manager shutdown.
2018-07-24 08:44:48,381 10502 INFO ? google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber._protocol.bidi: Thread-ConsumeBidirectionalStream exiting
2018-07-24 08:44:48,382 10502 INFO ? google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber._protocol.leaser: Thread-LeaseMaintainer exiting.
2018-07-24 08:44:48,383 10502 INFO ? google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber._protocol.heartbeater: Thread-Heartbeater exiting.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna close them manually:
[Using BASH how can i kill TCP port 16969?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825698/using-bash-how-can-i-kill-tcp-port-16969)
To do that, need to execute scrip inside docker container (https://hackernoon.com/run-bash-or-any-command-in-a-docker-container-9a1e7f0ec204)

The problem why you have so many open connections is that you terminate the program before `future.close()` is called. To solve this, might use atexit module:

```
import atexit

future = future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

@atexit.register
def goodbye():
    future.close()
    print("You are now leaving the Python sector.")
```